# Freeform Recipients not working

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

EE 2.9.3
FF 4.2.2

I've got a Freeform form where I'm using recipients, but it's not sending emails to the recipients.  However if I use notify_admin and admin_notify with the same notification template that email gets sent.

clearly emails are able to be sent but using recipients is not working. I've checked and checked and am unable to find any typos or obvious mistakes. Have also copied code to a blank template and it continues to behave incorrectly.

```
    {exp:freeform:form 
      form_id="1" 
      form:class="form-horizontal" 
      required="" 
      return="contact/thank-you" 
      status="open"
      notify_admin="yes"
      admin_notify="fake@mydomain.com"
      admin_notification_template="contact_notification" 
      recipient_template="contact_notification"
      recipients="yes"
      recipient1="John|none@domain.com"
      recipient2="Stacy|none1@domain.com"
      recipient3="Bill|none2@domain.com"
    }

      <fieldset>

        <!-- Select Basic -->
        <div class="form-group">

            <select id="province" name="province" class="form-control">

              <option required class="orange">Contact Person</option>

              {freeform:recipients}
                  <option
                      value="{freeform:recipient_value}"
                      {if freeform:recipient_selected}selected="selected"{/if}>
                      {freeform:recipient_name}
                  </option>
              {/freeform:recipients}
            </select>

        </div>

more fields here

      {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your opening select tag should be, I believe:

```
<select name="recipient_email">
```

And not what you have name="province", from https://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipient_email

```
<label>Choose Recipients</label>
<select name="recipient_email">
{freeform:recipients}
    <option
        value="{freeform:recipient_value}"
        {if freeform:recipient_selected}selected="selected"{/if}>
        {freeform:recipient_name}
    </option>
{/freeform:recipients}
</select>
```